# Pass in lists in the Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multicore, parallel.foreach

This is the first time I try to use the "Parallel.ForEach" loop to see if I can improve performance using many cores in the system. I have tried to look at MSDN and other examples but I can't find a way to pass in 3 lists as below.

How can this loop be exchanged with a Parallel.ForEach loop?
I think I am looking for the basics how to pass in all those 3 lists so I can work with them in the Parallel.ForEach loop?

Thank you!

```
        List<double> nums = new List<double> { 0.0005, 0.00035, 0.00205 };
        List<double> list1 = new List<double>();
        List<double> list2 = new List<double>();
        List<double> list3 = new List<double>(); Random random = new Random(); double calc1 = 0;
        List<double> resultLIST = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)
        {
            list1.Add(nums[random.Next(0, 7)]);
            list2.Add(nums[random.Next(0, 7)]);
            list3.Add(nums[random.Next(0, 7)]);
        }

        //How can the below loop be replaced with a: Parallel.ForEach loop?
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            calc1 = list1[i] * list2[i] * list3[i];
            resultLIST.Add(calc1);
        }

        //Now sort the list 
        resultLIST.Sort();

        //Here I will write "resultLIST" to a .txt file
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. We don't know what `list2` or` list3` represent, or what you intend to do with them. If you want to simply tag one list onto the end of the previous, then you could use `list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3)`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: As a side note, your first line can be replaced with `List<double> nums = new List<double> { 0.0005, 0.00035, 0.00205 };`

Comment: This is very low quality, please explain what you want to do with this, and why. As it stands there is no question here, just a thought bubble

Comment: I am sorry if my question is confusing. It is the first time I use this Parallel.ForEach loop so I am not sure if I miss something when putting the code. I have changed the question if that makes it more clear?

Comment: Is `calc1` supposed to be defined outside the loop? It doesn't make sense at the moment because only the last list items would actually factor into the final result.

Comment: Yes calc1 should be defined outside the loop. I have added code to my example to show a complete example. I am not sure how to do the example more clear or if I miss something anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use LINQ with `AsParallel`:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, list1.Count)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(index => list1[index] + list2[index] + list3[index])
    .OrderBy(v => v)
    .ToList();
```

Note that `list1`, `list2` and `list3` are not expected to change during this calculation.

Comment: That looks very new to me, I am not sure I can follow what is happening there. Is that the same as a Parallel.ForEach loop? I beleive I have to look into this. Why do you prefer this method before using the Parallel.ForEach loop. Is it a faster approach and do the method make use of as many cores there are in the system like for example 24 cores?

Comment: I prefer it because it means that I don't have to manually synchronise a result list, or use a `ConcurrentBag`, etc. You can read the docs for `AsParallel` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: I'd even go with the slightly simpler `Enumerable.Range(0, 4000000).AsParallel().Select(i => list1[i] * list2[i] * list3[i]).ToList()`.

Comment: Now, just as a bit of a side-note: with the `.OrderBy(v => v)` then using `.AsParallel()`, but without the `.OrderBy(v => v)` it is faster to do this without the `.AsParallel()`.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I think I will need to read the documentation on AsParallel so I know more about the basics. The approaches are very interesting to look into.

Comment: @Enigmativity I figured that was likely with the light-weight data set OP has (I didn't think about it quite as in-depth as you did, however).

Answer (score 0):

You use the Parallel.Foreach when the operations on each list can run independently in parallel. In your case you cannot. Also remember using Parallel.Foreach or AsParallel for trivial operations like * or + can actual degrade performance because there is more overhead.

In your case the best approach will be to split all three lists with 1000000 elements each. Add them into an array of array and call Parallel.Foreach on them. That way you will have 4 threads doing 1000000 operations each and if your machine has 4 cores they can run independently on each core.